# Using authenticationDatabase option while connecting to mongodb from nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I connect to mongodb from shell using `mongo` I need to use the following
`mongo -u xxxx -p xxxx --authenticationDatabase admin` then I get full access... but I cannot find a way to specify the `authenticationDatabase` while connecting from **nodejs** this is my code

```
var MongoCli = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/contactapp";

MongoCli.connect(url,function(err,db){
    if(err)
    {
        console.log('Unable to connect');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('Connected at ',url);
        db.authenticate('username','password','--authenticationDatabase admin',function(err,res){
            if(err)
            {
                console.log('Error');
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('Auth Success');
                var collection = db.collection('contact');
        collection.find().toArray(function(err,res){
            if(err)
            {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else if(res.length)
            {
                console.log('Found ',res);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('No data found');
            }
        db.close();
        });    
            }
        }); 
    }
});
```

I need to use the `authenticationDatabase`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
db.authenticate('username','password','--authenticationDatabase admin',function(err,res){
```

Whit this:

```
db.admin().authenticate('username', 'password', function(err,res){
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question on using `authenticationDatabase` with nodeJS, mongodb and mongoose. Passing the whole path with credentials and a flag worked for me

`mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/databaseName?authSource=admin`

`authSource` is a flag for `authenticationDatabase`